# Navigation controller Set title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have created an application using UINavigationController. So now when i go from one view to another, i get the title of the [previous screen displayed as the back button of the new view](http://www.kickasslabs.com/~kal_www/kickasslabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/navcontricks2.png).

Sometimes if the name of the previous screen is long, i get a longer title for the back button, instead of having the long name of the previous screen is there a way for me to only have the text `BACK` ?

Comment: Bear in mind, from a user interface design stand point, that your back button should always inform the user where they are going back to, and a back button labeled back isn't very helpful

Comment: But say if i have a very long title in the previous view. and that name gets displayed on the present view. Its too long and ugly.

Comment: Think of how you can express that title in one word and make the button say that. Maybe that one word even works better as the title... Part of designing for the iPhone is that we mustn't compromise on the user interface. If we sweat every detail like apple does then our products end up better, our users end up happier and we all sell more stuff. At least thats the theory :)

Comment: @jackslash I agree, i shall leave it as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. On the previous screen, you can create a bar button item for the back button.

Simply create a UIBarButtonItem with a nil target and a nil selector, but with the title "Back", then in your previous screen, use the `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` property and set that as your UIBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your own button and add it to your UINavigationController.

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
 target:nil action:nil];
  self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
  [backButton release];
```

But remember to do it not in the viewController where your back button appears, but **in the viewController where you go back after tapping your back button**.